# Auto fill doesn't work on edit with image uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image-uploading

I trying to create a blog with a obligatory image, but after create, when i try to edit this blog, his image appears on thmbnail but not in field and 
i have to select the image again.

For upload image i use the carrierwave gem.

My model

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name, :description, :picture, presence: true

mount_uploader :picture, BlogPictureUploader

def picture_url
  picture.url
end
```

My view

```
= simple_form_for [blog] do |f|
 .row
  .col-md-6
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading Foto
      .panel-body
        .thumbnail class="#{blog.picture? ? "" : "hide"}"
          = image_tag blog.picture
        p= f.input :picture, label: 'Selecione a foto:', hint: 'A foto deve ter 270x270.'
```

My controller

```
 class BlogsController < ApplicationController
 expose(:blog, attributes: :blog_params)

 def update
   authorize blog
   blog.save
   respond_with blog, location: [:blog]
 end
```

The behavior on edit: [edit view after click button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaqbC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would create a `img` element for displaying the image in your edit-page, that was originally uploaded. You don't necessarily have to use the path of the original-image in your `input` element at the edit-page, and IF the user uploads a new picture it will replace the old one.